# Phusion Passenger malloc failed error on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: malloc, passenger

Starting passenger with:

> $ LOAD_FAST=true passenger start --pid-file tmp/x.pid

results in the following error:

```
App 65478 output: PassengerAgent(65481,0x7fffb856e380) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=268435459)
App 65478 output: PassengerAgent(65481,0x7fffb856e380) malloc: *** error: can't allocate region securely
App 65478 output: PassengerAgent(65481,0x7fffb856e380) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Yet, *most* of the time the passenger server continues to run and serve the application. Of the 16GB RAM, there is usually 3GB available.

Here is some configuration information:

```
$ brew info passenger
     passenger: stable 5.3.3 (bottled), HEAD
     Server for Ruby, Python, and Node.js apps via Apache/NGINX
     https://www.phusionpassenger.com/
     /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.2.3 (4,380 files, 179.2MB)
       Poured from bottle on 2018-04-06 at 14:33:38
     /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.3.3 (4,380 files, 181MB) *
       Poured from bottle on 2018-07-17 at 14:42:01
     From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/passenger.rb
     ==> Dependencies
     Required: pcre ✔, openssl ✔
     ==> Requirements
     Required: macOS >= 10.7 ✔
     ==> Caveats
     To activate Phusion Passenger for Nginx, run:
       brew install nginx --with-passenger
    /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
              PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby

$ /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/bin/passenger-config about make-locations-ini   # update reference to new passenger
[locations]
packaging_method=unknown
bin_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/bin
support_binaries_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/buildout/support-binaries
lib_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/buildout
helper_scripts_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/src/helper-scripts
resources_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/resources
include_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/src
doc_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/doc
ruby_libdir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/src/ruby_supportlib
node_libdir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/src/nodejs_supportlib
apache2_module_path=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
ruby_extension_source_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/src/ruby_native_extension
nginx_module_source_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/src/nginx_module
build_system_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3
download_cache_dir=/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@athn_web/gems/passenger-5.3.3/download_cache

$ passenger-status                                                                                                                                                   (/Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1) -I-
Version : 5.3.3
Date    : 2018-07-18 10:33:31 -0600
Instance: qXs24Ztd (nginx/1.14.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.3.3)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 1
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/Users/developer/workspace/advoy-rails (development):
  App root: /Users/developer/workspace/advoy-rails
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 65519   Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 36m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 148M    Last used: 36m 15s ago
```

Comment: Per https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2101 - We're aware of these warnings. They are currently harmless, though annoying. They're difficult to reproduce under a debugger, and I don't currently have time to do so, given that they don't actually cause any issues besides logspam.